# Creating a CustomUserControl with a DependencyProperty of type ObservableCollection

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to create a CustomUserControl in WPF.
This CustomUserControl contains a DependencyProperty of type ObservableCollection.

My goal is to be able to:

- Be able to set the collection directly in the xaml code
- Be able to bind the collection to a collection in my ViewModel
- Be able to set the collection using a style setter
- Have a different instance of the collection per instance of my CustomUserControl.

Here is what I have right now:

```
<my:CustomUserControl ImageList={Binding imgList}/>
```

ImageList is defined as the following:

```
public static readonly DependancyProperty ImageListProperty = DependancyProperty.Register
  ("ImageList", typeof(List<ImageSource>), typeof(Switch));

public List<ImageSource> ImageList {
  get { return (List<ImageSource>)GetValue(ImageListProperty); }
  set { SetValue(ImageListProperty, value); }
}
```

In order to have a new instance of ImageList per CustomUserControl, I have added the following line in the ctor of CustomUserControl:

```
public CustomUserControl(){
...
SetValue(ImageListProperty, new List<ImageSource>());
}
```

Now, the following code examples work:

```
<my:CustomUserControl>
  <my:CustomUserControl.ImageList>
    <BitmapImage UriSource="Bla.png"/>
    <BitmapImage UriSource="Bla2.png"/>
  </my:CustomUserControl.ImageList>
</my:switch>
```

And this works too:

```
<my:CustomUserControl ImageList={Binding imgList}/>
```

But this **does not**:

```
<Style TargetType="my:CustomUserControl">
<Setter Property="my:CustomUserControl.ImageList">
        <BitmapImage UriSource="Bla.png"/>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="Bla2.png"/>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

This leaves all instances with an empty ImageList.

P.S. This is pseudo-code as I don't recall the exact syntax.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you aren't able to set the value in a `Style` is because you are setting a local value in your constructor. [MSDN explains `DependencyProperty` value precedence in more detail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx).

Because you just want to give your property a default value per instance, just use [`SetCurrentValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue.aspx) instead of `SetValue` in your constructor.

**Edit to explain this further**

So, a `DependencyProperty` can be set in multiple ways. It can be set through code, a `Binding`, a `Style`, a `Trigger`, an `Animation`, or a few other ways. The important thing to know is that there can be multiple attempts to set a given property.

Because of this, WPF has defined a precedence for the values. That means if you set a property in a `Style`, you can set the property manually to override the `Style` value. Or a `Trigger` in the `ControlTemplate` can override the `Style` value.

When you set the property in your constructor, you are giving it a *local value*. From the first link, you will see that **only** an `Animation` or `Property Coercion` can override a local value.

The `SetCurrentValue` method, however, will allow you to set a value for a property [*without setting a local value*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#setcurrentvalue). This is what you need, as you want to be able to set the value in a `Style`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved the problem. I tried reading online to understand this function, but I couldn't understand how it solved the issue in this case. Would you mind explaining in a few words? Thanks again!

Comment: @Berlo I've added to the answer to try to explain this more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `List<ImageSource>` you should use `CompositeCollection` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx))

```
public CompositeCollection ImageList
{
    get { return (CompositeCollection)GetValue(ImageListProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ImageListProperty, value); }
}      
public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageListProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ImageList", typeof(CompositeCollection), typeof(CustomUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(new CompositeCollection()));
```

And now you can set values in the defined style like this:

```
<my:CustomUserControl x:Name="myCustomUserControl   
    <my:CustomUserControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type my:CustomUserControl}">
            <Setter Property="my:CustomUserControl.ImageList">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <CompositeCollection>
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="Bla.png"/>
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="Bla2.png"/>
                    </CompositeCollection>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </my:CustomUserControl.Style>            
</my:CustomUserControl>
```

Other binding works in the same way as you presented in your question.

e.g.:

```
<my:CustomUserControl x:Name="myCustomUserControl">
    <my:CustomUserControl.ImageList>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="Bla.png" />
        <BitmapImage UriSource="Bla2.png" />
    </my:CustomUserControl.ImageList>            
</my:CustomUserControl>
```